# SQL 2016 - NU/NC Index Missing From sys.partitions

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, nonclustered-index

Is there a reason that a non-unique, non-clustered index would have 0 corresponding records in the sys.partitions view?  There is a CI on the same table and there is a record for it in the view.  My understanding is that any NCI should have at least one record in sys.partitions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A disabled index has no storage.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks mate.

Comment: I guess shortest answer I have seen on this forum :)